# CentOS linux minimal upgrading to GUI interface getting server error

Tags: centos, xorg, gnome, virtual-desktop, x-windows

After install GNOME Desktop, X Windows System in CentOS linux and ***startx*** command getting Server Error as follows.

```
xauth:  file /root/.serverauth.25996 does not exist

X.Org X Server 1.17.4
Release Date: 2015-10-28
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: c1bm 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64
Current Operating System: Linux TestCentOS 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed
Mar 11 22:03:14 UTC 2015 x86_64

Kernel command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.
UTF-8 rd_NO_MD console=hvc0  KEYTABLE=us rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_swap SYSFONT=lata
rcyrheb-sun16  rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_root rd_NO_DM rhgb quiet graphical utf8
Build Date: 22 March 2017  02:59:47AM
Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.17.4-16.el6.centos

Current version of pixman: 0.32.8
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.centos.org/Documentation
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Aug 29 13:52:53 2017
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)

Please consult the CentOS support
         at http://wiki.centos.org/Documentation
 for help.

(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional info
rmation.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

giving up.
xinit:  Connection refused (errno 111):  unable to connect to X server
xinit:  No such process (errno 3):  Server error.
```

Comment: Are you saying that you used CentOS packages to upgrade a RHEL minimal installation?

Comment: Actually I try to upgarde CentOS minimal to CentOS Desktop. Still I cannot resolve the issue